No puedo insertar los datos en mi base de datos
Este es mi código de php ya lo revise y tengo bien las variables y en donde se van a insertar, me manda el siguente error Error: Error al preparar la consulta: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 me salió es error, toda esta información se manda de html a php con ajax.
La lo que se manda del form de html esta en un wrapper, si llegan a ocupar el html subire fotos ya que esta muy largo el codigo.
si no estoy mal el error debe de venir de la parte del insert o bind_param, pero desde mi punto de vista esta bien.
  <?php
// Parámetros de conexión
$host = 'localhost';
$dbname = 'dibujo';
$username = 'root';
$password = '';

// Crear conexión
$conn = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Verificar conexión
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die(json_encode(["status" => "error", "message" => "Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error]));
}

// Revisar si hay datos POST
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    // Recibir datos del formulario
    $orden = $_POST['orden'];
    $sales_rep = $_POST['sales_rep'];
    $status = $_POST['status'];
    $drawing_type = $_POST['drawing_type'];
    $frame_shape = $_POST['frame_shape'];
    $eyebrow_size = $_POST['eyebrow_size'];
    $door_shape = $_POST['door_shape'];
    $do_you_need_glass = $_POST['do_you_need_glass'];
    $glass_shape = $_POST['glass_shape'];
    $glass_function = $_POST['glass_function'];
    $type_of_glass = $_POST['type_of_glass'];
    $quantity_of_glass = $_POST['quantity_of_glass'];
    $jambo_size = $_POST['jambo_size'];
    $threshold_type = $_POST['threshold_type'];
    $threshold_gap = $_POST['threshold_gap'];
    $need_trims = $_POST['need_trims'];
    $trim_in = $_POST['trim_in'];
    $trim_out = $_POST['trim_out'];
    $handle_quantity = $_POST['handle_quantity'];
    $handle_type = $_POST['handle_type'];
    $handle_installation = $_POST['handle_installation'];
    $scrollwork = $_POST['scrollwork'];
    $desing_in_and_out = $_POST['desing_in_and_out'];
    $door_swing = $_POST['door_swing'];
    $door_operation = $_POST['door_operation'];
    $door_has_transom = $_POST['door_has_transom'];
    $info_needed = $_POST['info_needed'];
    $priority = $_POST['priority'];
    $managments_approve = $_POST['managments_approve'];
    $who_approved_it = $_POST['who_approved_it'];
    $initial_date = $_POST['initial_date'];
    $final_date = $_POST['final_date'];
    $door_color = $_POST['door_color'];
    $type_of_paint = $_POST['type_of_paint'];
    $designName = $_POST['designName'];
    $measurement = $_POST['measurement'];
    $additional_information = $_POST['additional_information'];

    // Subir archivos y obtener rutas
    $designFilePath = uploadFile('designFile', 'designs/');
    $layoutFilePath = uploadFile('layoutFile', 'layouts/');
    $measurementFilePath = uploadFile('measurementFile', 'measurements/');
    $upload_measurments = uploadFile('upload_measurments', 'upload_measurments/');

    // Verificar si los archivos fueron subidos correctamente
    if ($designFilePath === null || $layoutFilePath === null || $measurementFilePath === null || $upload_measurments === null) {
        echo json_encode(["status" => "error", "message" => "Error: No todos los archivos fueron subidos correctamente."]);
        exit;
    }

    $sql = "INSERT INTO dibujo (
        orden, person,, sales_rep, status, drawing_type, frame_shape, eyebrow_size, door_shape, 
        do_you_need_glass, glass_shape, glass_function, type_of_glass, quantity_of_glass, jambo_size, 
        threshold_type, threshold_gap, need_trims, trim_in, trim_out, handle_quantity, handle_type, 
        handle_installation, scrollwork, desing_in_and_out, door_swing, door_operation, door_has_transom, 
        upload_measurments, info_needed, priority, managments_approve, who_approved_it, initial_date, 
        final_date, door_color, type_of_paint, designName, designFile, layoutFile, measurement, additional_information, 
        measurementFile, jpg_archivo, cad_archivo, fecha_inicio_status, hora_inicio_status, 
        fecha_final_status, hora_final_status
    ) VALUES (
        ?, NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 
        ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
    )";
    
    // Preparar la consulta
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    
    if ($stmt === false) {
        echo json_encode(["status" => "error", "message" => "Error al preparar la consulta: " . $conn->error]);
        exit;
    }

    // Vincular parámetros y ejecutar consulta
    $stmt->bind_param(
        "sssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss", 
        $orden, $sales_rep, $status, $drawing_type, $frame_shape, $eyebrow_size, $door_shape, 
        $do_you_need_glass, $glass_shape, $glass_function, $type_of_glass, $quantity_of_glass, $jambo_size, 
        $threshold_type, $threshold_gap, $need_trims, $trim_in, $trim_out, $handle_quantity, $handle_type, 
        $handle_installation, $scrollwork, $desing_in_and_out, $door_swing, $door_operation, $door_has_transom, 
        $upload_measurments, $info_needed, $priority, $managments_approve, $who_approved_it, $initial_date, 
        $final_date, $door_color, $type_of_paint, $designName, $designFilePath, $layoutFilePath, $measurement, $additional_information, 
        $measurementFilePath
    );
    
    if ($stmt->execute() === false) {
        echo json_encode(["status" => "error", "message" => "Error al ejecutar la consulta: " . $stmt->error]);
        exit;
    }

    $stmt->close();
    echo json_encode(["status" => "success", "message" => "Datos insertados correctamente."]);
}

function uploadFile($inputName, $uploadDir) {
    if (!isset($_FILES[$inputName]) || $_FILES[$inputName]['error'] != 0) {
        return null; // Retornar null si no hay archivo o si hay error
    }
    $filePath = $uploadDir . basename($_FILES[$inputName]['name']);
    if (!is_dir($uploadDir)) {
        mkdir($uploadDir, 0777, true); // Crear la carpeta si no existe
    }
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$inputName]['tmp_name'], $filePath)) {
        return $filePath; // Retornar la ruta del archivo si la carga es exitosa
    } else {
        return null; // Retornar null si hay error al mover el archivo
    }
}
?>

Este es mi ajax, se manda al php correcto
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#submitButton').on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault(); // Evita el envío del formulario por defecto
        var formData = new FormData($('#designForm')[0]);
        
        $.ajax({
            url: 'submit_design.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function(response) {
                var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(response);
                if (jsonResponse.status === 'success') {
                    alert('Éxito: ' + jsonResponse.message);
                } else {
                    alert('Error: ' + jsonResponse.message);
                }
            },
            error: function() {
                alert('Error al enviar el formulario.');
                
            }
        });
    });
});


ok el error es claro... dice que el numero de columnas no concuerdan con el numero de columnas necesaria... entonces para poder ayudarte, realmente necesesitamos 1 el query que esta dando el error, 2 la estructura de la base de datos ...

ten en cuenta que esto no tiene nada que ver con el ajax ... siempre y cuando ya a estas alturas hayas validado que toda la informacion que necesitas a viajado del html(frontend) hasta el PHP (Bakcend)... si esto no lo has validado es lo primero que debes hacer antes de intentar meter datos a la base de datos ...

forma rapida de saber si con semejante cantidad de parametros estan todos los que tienen que estar??? conta las comas ;)..

A simple vista se observa una coma de más en esta parte de la consulta: person, , ¿o quizá falta en ese espacio el nombre de una columna? Puede que haya más fallos, simplemente revisa minuciosamente esa consulta y verifica que marcadores y parámetros corresponden.

Primero: hay doble coma después de 'persona' (¿es una coma extra o debe ir el nombre de una columna?). Segundo: envías solamente 46 valores para 49 columnas (o 48, dependiendo cómo resuelvas el asunto de la coma doble). La cantidad de valores enviados debe coincidir con la cantidad de columnas especificadas en tu consulta.
